# Get hold of html element with @ViewChild only after the element is created

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have an Angular component with an html element in its template. I want to be able to create the element when a certain Observable emits any value. Therefore I have coded the element like this

```
<div #myDiv *ngIf="myObs | async"> this is my div </div>
```

where `myObs` is the Observable.

At the same time I want to manage this element programmatically and therefore I use `ViewChild` like this

```
@ViewChild('myDiv') myDiv: ElementRef;
....
ngAfterViewInit() {
  const myNativeElement = this.myDiv.nativeElement;
  doStuffWith(myNativeElement);
}
```

My issue is that when `ngAfterViewInit` runs, `this.myDiv` is null and only after `myObs` emits it is created.

I am wondering which is the best way make sure `doStuffWith(myNativeElement)` is executed only when `this.myDiv` is actually created.

[This is a sample code to reproduce the case](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-q6fvmf?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would use a setter on the `@ViewChild`:

```
@ViewChild('myDiv') set myDiv(myDiv: ElementRef) {
    doStuffWith(myDiv.nativeElement);
}
```

The setter will be called once `*ngIf` becomes `true`.

You can also keep a reference to your element by using a private property and setting it in the setter.

Comment: Thanks, this work. The thing I have noticed though is that the setter is called first time when the Component is created and then a second time when `myDiv` element is created as result of the Observable notification. This forces me to protect the logic with an `if(myDiv)` piece of logic. Anyways it works. Thanks.